# Pushout from initial object isomorphic to coproduct

Tags: category-theory

Let $C$ be a category with an initial object $0$, pushouts, and coproducts.
If $G$ and $H$ are two objects, I want to know whether $G\sqcup H$ and $G\sqcup_0 H$ are
isomorphic.
Letting $i_1$ and $i_2$ be the morphisms from $G$ and $H$ into $G\sqcup H$, and letting
$\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ be the morphisms from $G$ and $H$ into $G\sqcup_0 H$, I know there 
are two unique morphisms $i:G\sqcup_0 H\rightarrow G\sqcup H$ and $\phi:G\sqcup H\rightarrow
G\sqcup_0 H$ such that $\phi_1=\phi\circ i_1$, $\phi_2=\phi\circ i_2$, $i_1=i\circ \phi_1$,
and $i_2=i\circ \phi_2$.

That is, the following diagram is commutative:

$\hskip1in$ [image]

I believe I need to show $\phi\circ i=id_{G\sqcup H}$ and that $i\circ \phi=id_{G\sqcup_0 H}$,
as they are the only morphisms showing up. But now I am stuck.

This is just for personal interest. I'd appreciate any help finishing the proof, or 
demonstrating a counter-example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The identities $\phi\circ i=1_{G\sqcup H}$ and $i\circ\phi=1_{G\sqcup_O H}$ follows from unicity of the comparison morphisms from the pushout and from $G\sqcup H$.

For example, by universal property of pushout, there exists a unique morphism $f:G\sqcup_O H\to G\sqcup_O H$ such that $f\circ \phi_1=\phi_1$ and $f\circ \phi_2=\phi_2$, and this is the identity.

Answer (score 6):

As almost always the Yoneda Lemma offers a one-line proof.

$\small \hom(G \sqcup H,K) = \hom(G,K) \times \hom(H,K) = \hom(G,K) \times_{\hom(0,K)} \hom(H,K) = \hom(G \sqcup_0 H,K)$

Comment: Martin could you please justify/explain the second isomorphism and confirm whether the third formula is a pullback?

Comment: The second isomorphism is given by the fact that $\hom(0,K)$ is a single point. The last step is the same as the first one.